# How does CreateJs encrypt a path

Tags: html, createjs

I have following code which is responsible to generate a text, But i don't understand how does CreateJs is encrypting this text

```
this.shape_12.graphics.f("#00ADEA").s().p("Ag1Q...");
```

where `.p("")` is responsible for the rendering of text "Nursing",

I am stucked here because i want to change this text to the "MyArticle". any help how can i do this.

```
(lib.text_1_5 = function (mode, startPosition, loop) {
        this.initialize(mode, startPosition, loop, {});

        // timeline functions:
        this.frame_0 = function () {
            this.link = "Nursing";
            this.on("click", function (event) {
                canvasStageRef.onItemClick();
            });
        }

        // actions tween:
        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0));

        // Layer 1//fontcolor
        this.shape_10 = new cjs.Shape();
        this.shape_10.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("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");

        this.shape_10.setTransform(-1.5, -9);

        this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({ state: [{ t: this.myText }] }).wait(1));
```

above code is responsible to render text Nursing(in .p("ahskjhsja");)... plz suggest which thing i will replace to make it text that is not render with path... it can change manually..

if this is possible with Text than how i can acheive plz help.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got a solution with above answer .. and also giving exact right answer,, Thanks to @oleg and Lanny

```
this.shape= new cjs.Text("Cardic surgery", "bold 17px Arial", "#9aac5a");
            this.shape.setTransform(25, -118, 1.0, 1.0, 90, 0, 0, -30, 1.0);
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({ state: [{ t: this.shape }] }).wait(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an encryption but [path specification](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#method_decodePath) similar to path in SVG. You can define complex path by hand but when you need to draw a text data you should really try [Text](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Text.html) first.

Comment: Thnx for replying @oleg... I edit the question plz have a look and reply

Comment: You can turn off the compressed path in the publish settings. The path() method uses a custom format which describes each drawing command using a number then the instructions, which is then encoded to reduce the number if characters. You can check out the decodePath method on the easeljs Graphics class if you want to learn about how it works.

Comment: yes i solved the problem by my above answer.. But i also like to know about the path structre.. So can you provide me right articl that would help me to do so,,, @Lanny

Comment: Check out the source. You can see how the path is decoded. This is not really meant to understand, just to provide a compact export from Flash CC. http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/files/easeljs_display_Graphics.js.html#l1041